# Can I set uniform array of Sampler2D with glProgramUniform1iv()?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Here is what I have in a fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D directionalLightShadowmapSamplers[MAX_DIRECTIONAL_LIGHTS_PER_EXECUTE];
```

I was inserting values there by iterating over `MAX_DIRECTIONAL_LIGHTS_PER_EXECUTE` like so:

```
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i=0; i<MaxDirectionalLightsPerExecute; ++i) {
        ss << "directionalLightShadowmapSamplers" << '[' << i << ']';
        glProgramUniform1i(_program, glGetUniformLocation(_program, ss.str().c_str()), DirectionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocationBegin + i);
        ss.clear();
        ss.str(std::string());
    }
```

And it was working super fine.
But today I thought to myself "I can do better than that!" and I wanted to use `glProgramUniform1iv()` instead. Turns out - I can't:

```
std::array<GLint, MaxDirectionalLightsPerExecute> directionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocations;
std::iota(directionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocations.begin(), directionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocations.end(), DirectionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocationBegin);

glProgramUniform1iv(_program, glGetUniformLocation(_program, "directionalLightShadowmapSamplers"), MaxDirectionalLightsPerExecute, directionalLightShadowmapTexturesLocations.data());
```

What am I missing? Is the layout of sampler2D not as simple as I thought (just integer)? Should I align the array to size of vec4 on C++ side?

Comment: The string that you pass to `glGetUniformLocation` must be null-terminated.

Comment: There you go, it is now null-terminated. But it still doesn't answer the question

Comment: Anyway, it was a bug and could have caused the problem.

Comment: I had to cut a lot of code to make the question as simple and short as possible. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Why do you not use a layout qualifier?

Comment: Ok so what I'm doing now is a wrapper for uniform value. Usage looks like this:
UniformValue<UniformType::UnsignedInt>(_program, DirectionalLightsCountUniform).Set(directionalLightsCount);
In debug, it'll verify location, verify type, verify all u need to know. Sample code is just minimum for the question. I change shaders pretty often, so I query location. Otherwise I'd have to update C++ side for mapping as well.
Location is queried once per UniformValue instance too.

Comment: Sorry, but in this case I am not sure. I know if you are using a layout qualifier, then *"Individual elements of a uniform array are assigned consecutive locations with the first element taking location location."* (see [Layout Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#layout-qualifiers)). However, I don't know if this also applies if you don't use a layout qualifier.

Comment: If you don't use layout qualifier, it'll basically assign the location implicitly as it wishes, most likely by the order you just put it in the shader. So first uniform would be 0, 2nd one would be 1 etc.

Comment: *"most likely by the order you just put it in the shader"* No. The order of uniform locations (and other locations) is not guaranteed by the specification. Yes, it probably is, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: yes, that's why "most likely" (that's what I see when debugging) and that's why I query it before use to make sure I have correct value. It's all good here

Comment: Anyway it is fine to set an array of samplers with `*Uniform1iv`. See [7.6.1 Loading Uniform Variables In The Default Uniform Block](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=163&zoom=100,168,173)

Comment: @Rabbid76: "*However, I don't know if this also applies if you don't use a layout qualifier.*" It does.

Comment: @Rabbid76 lol true! it says I can do that easy... Post it as answer and let's finish this. Seems like once again the issue is right between the chair and the keyboard. I'll try to figure what else could be wrong so it didn't work for me